# Execution error in store procedure SP_AUTOMATE_TYPE2: SQL compilation error: invalid identifier 'F58139' At Snowflake.execute

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a table called CategoryName in the  schema and below picture, I have made just one entry as shown below
[image]

The below procedure is written in snowflake in Javascript, however when i run this procedure and call sp_automate_type2(F58139) it gives me an error in the headline

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_automate_type2 (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARIANT NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var command = "select CATEGORY FROM STORE_PROFILE_LANDING.LANDING.CATEGORYName// cat WHERE 
cat.TABLE_NAMES=" + TABLE_NAME;
var results1 = snowflake.execute({sqlText: command});
var category = ""
while (results1.next()){
    category = category + results1.getColumnValue('CATEGORY')
}
$$
```

I wanted the above code to identify table name as 'type 2' and pass through below part of the procedure,  what can be done??

```
   if (CATEGORY=='TYPE 2' or CATEGORY='type 2'){
   // finds the primary keys of the given input table and stores it in an array.

  var command = "describe table landing." + TABLE_NAME;
  var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: command});
  var primary_keys = [];
  while (result.next()){
      if (result.getColumnValue('primary key')=='Y'){
        primary_keys.push(result.getColumnValue('name'));
      }
      else{
          continue;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why is there a comment marker on the line starting with "var command" before the where clause? The way it is here, it won't compile. Removing the line break from the SQL statement makes the // comment marker interfere with the where clause. Can you post the entire SP?

Comment: yes @GregPavlik

Comment: @GregPavlik unable to post entire sp as it is too big

Comment: Can you change this line to wrap '' around your string?

    var command = "select CATEGORY FROM STORE_PROFILE_LANDING.LANDING.CATEGORYName// cat WHERE 
    cat.TABLE_NAMES='" + TABLE_NAME + "'";